# How to upload text file and import its data in sql using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a core PHP script which allows me to upload text file and import its data into sql database.

I want to do the same thing using **Codeigniter**. I tried by the screen shows me blank white screen when i put the code in CI application.

Below Is My core PHP script for uploading a file and Importing It:

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
{    

    $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $folder="uploads/";
    $location =$_FILES['file'];

    // new file size in KB
    $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
    // new file size in KB

    // make file name in lower case
    $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
    // make file name in lower case

    $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

        if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
    {
        $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(file,type,size) VALUES('$final_file','$file_type','$new_size')";
        mysqli_query($connection,$sql);


        $handle = fopen("c:/wamp/www/codeigniter/uploads/$file", "r");

         if ($handle) {
                while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

                     $lineArr = explode("\t", "$line");
                     //var_dump($lineArr); // to make sure array is ok

                     // instead assigning one by onb use php list -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php            
                     list($emp_id, $date_data, $abc, $def, $entry, $ghi) = $lineArr;

                     // and then insert data
                     mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO `daily_data2` (emp_id, date_data, abc, def, entry, ghi) 
            VALUES ('$emp_id', '$date_data', '$abc', '$def', '$entry', '$ghi')");
                }

                fclose($handle);
            }


        ?>
        <script>
        alert('successfully uploaded');
        window.location.href='index.php?success';
        </script>
        <?php


    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script>
        alert('error while uploading file');
        window.location.href='index.php?fail';
        </script>
        <?php
    }

}

?>
```

I dont know how to do this in Codeigniter. Please guide me here

**the Ci Form:**

```
     <h2>Upload CSV To Import Users</h2>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('admin/attendance/upload');?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="userfile"  ><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPLOAD" class="btn btn-primary">
        </form>
```

Comment: why you not use Codeigniter Database methods to this??

Comment: i want to use codeigniter method for this but i dont know how to do it @Abdulla

Comment: @Abdulla I tried to do the same in CI but failed

Comment: is uploded file CSV ??

Comment: @Abdulla Not its a text file that is tab seprated

Comment: Ok will give some codes. try that. make sure your read file code is working on tht. ok

Comment: Okay i will try @Abdulla My pure php code is working fine but i dont know how to do it in Codeigniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Controller**

```
## include_once 'dbconfig.php';
## Use defult Databse connection

if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
{    

    $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $folder="uploads/";
    $location =$_FILES['file'];

    $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
    $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
    $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);
    $new_name = $folder.$final_file;

    if(!move_uploaded_file($final_file,$new_name)) # Change This
            echo "Error in Upload";
        }
        else{

            $file_uploded = base_url().'uploads/'.$file;

            if (!file_exists($file_uploded)) {
                echo "File Not exist";
            }
            else
            {
                $handle = fopen($file_uplod_path, "r") or die("file cannot open");

                if ($handle) {
                    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) 
                    {
                        $lineArr = explode("\t", "$line");    

                        $result = $this->model_name->insert_file_content($lineArr) ;    
                    }
                    if (fclose($handle)) {
                        redirect(base_url());
                    }

                } 
                else{
                    echo "file cannot open";
                } 
            }
        }      
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Moveing failed";

    }

}
```

**In Model**

```
public function insert_file_details($final_file,$file_type,$new_size)
{

    $data = array(
       'file' => $final_file,
       'type' => $file_type,
       'size' => $new_size,
    );

    if (!$this->db->insert('table_name', $data)) {
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }

}

# inserting file in to DB
public function insert_file_content($lineArr)
{

    $data = array(
       'emp_id'     => $lineArr[0],
       'date_data'  => $lineArr[1],
       'abc'        => $lineArr[2],
       'def'        => $lineArr[3],
       'entry'      => $lineArr[4],
       'ghi'        => $lineArr[5],
    );

   $this->db->insert('table_name', $data);
}
```

Comment: Not tested. So bugs may be there carefully handle those

Comment: Yes Okay. For Now it shows me a white screen when i upload any file

Comment: change this   `if(move_uploaded_file($final_file,$folder))`

Comment: i think there is problem with my form as you see the form

Comment: in my controller i am checking if(isset($_POST['btn-upload'])) is this correct?

Comment: no need there is form action?? so set it to this controller method. So no need of use this

Comment: file upload is form an form??

Comment: Yes i have a view in which i have file upload form

Comment: so action set to controller and remove isset part fromit

Comment: When i upload the file it returns file not exists what does this mean?

Comment: think file not uploaded. check your permition  of the folder and make sure its uploaded

Comment: Permission are correct my folder structure is: I have my project folder in that i have created a folder called uploads along with other CI folder application system etc]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97965/discussion-between-abdulla-and-rajan).

Comment: Okay Lets Discuss there

Comment: Shows Me Error in Upload @abdulla

Comment: I worked on the code and finally got it working. Your code helped me a lot thanks buddy

Answer (score 2):

Seriously dudes, there is the **File Uploading Class** with CodeIgniter, it's free, powerfull, errors catching and soooo simply !!

Please, see :

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

I sincerely hope you'll use it :)